# MongoCursorException 'couldn't get response header'

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am developing a website using PHP and mongodb. I access the mongodb with [PECL-mongo](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo), and have run into an annoyance. Every now and then, I get an error like this (I've anonymized the paths)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'couldn't get response header' in
    /PATH/index.php:38 Stack trace: #0 
    /PATH/index.php(38): MongoCursor->rewind() #1 
    /PATH/template.inc(29): get_sidebar() #2 
    /PATH/index.php(13): 
    require_once('PATH/...') #3 {main} thrown in PATH/index.php on line 38
```

According to the documentation, this means:

> The driver could not fetch a reply header from the database, so it
>   gave up. Check if the database is still up and the network is
>   connected and try the query again.

But I **know** that the database is up because I am doing this locally on my own machine over loopback. No connection is made to the outside world.

Simply trying again often works. Is this a possibly a bug in PHP's driver for mongo? Could this be a "miscompile" issue (I compiled from source, but with very benign flags, `-march=native -O2`)?

Has anyone seen this before?

Searching around, I only see references to some stupid facebook game having the same error.

**EDIT**: I just downgraded my PECL driver to version 1.1.4 and **so far**, the problem seems have gone away. So this may simply be a bug in the 1.2.x series. If anyone can shed any light on it, that would be great.

**EDIT**: I am not doing anything complex here, the code that is having the issue litterally looks like this:

```
$m = new Mongo();
$collection = $m->my_db->collection;
$results = $collection->find(array("favorite"=>true))->limit(5);
```

Comment: So first note, you definitely want to catch the Exception. There may be a bug here, but without catching the Exception and logging data, it's hard to know what happened. Was there a failed Query? A failed Update/Insert/Delete? Are you cursoring through data when this happens?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue as you. What solution did you end up implementing? I'm stuck with an ugly loop that checks for the exception =/

Comment: I just downgraded my PECL driver to version 1.1.4. And it seems solid now.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like the new version of the PHP Mongo driver handles connections a little better (released yesterday): http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=mongo&release=1.2.7 This might solve your problem without having to run an old version of the driver.

Answer (score 1):

i solved this problem with get new version mogodb.dll 
you can see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center

Comment: are you trying to say "problem"? what is a "pelbome", you've said it twice now.